# Quando branches são uteis no Git?

Tags: git

Estou estudando Git e pelo que vi sobre branches basicamente identifiquei duas situações principais nas quais branches são úteis:

1. Quando temos uma versão estável do código na branch master e queremos adicionar uma nova funcionalidade, criamos então uma branch pra desenvolver a funcionalidade sem ter o perigo de quebrar o que já temos na branch master.
2. Quando temos uma versão estável do código na branch master e precisamos corrigir algum bug encontrado, criamos uma branch pra trabalhar nesse bug e não corremos o risco de danificar o código estável

Esses dois usos parecem que são bem comuns, porque também já vi em muitos artigos e vídeos eles serem citados. A questão é que já ouvi falar também que usuários mais experientes do Git recomendam fazer bastante uso de branches. Vi uma vez até uma resposta no Stack Overflow em inglês que falava que o ideal é começar a fazer branches mais cedo e sempre usar branches.

Acontece que nesses dois casos que identifiquei que branches seriam úteis, a utilidade vem do fato de existir um código estável que não é interessante mexer muito e querermos ter a liberdade de trabalhar em algo sem estragar esse código. Não consigo ver como que antes de termos um código estável branching possa ser útil.

Dessa forma, quando branches são realmente úteis no Git e por que essa recomendação de começar a usar branches desde o inicio e usar sempre?

Comment: Ou mais de uma versão de código estável, por exemplo uma nova versão com mudanças radicas na estrutura do código. Li a algum tempo sobre [gitflow](http://danielkummer.github.io/git-flow-cheatsheet/), acho uma boa dar uma lida.

Answer (score 15):

O Git oferece os recursos mas a sua questão tem mais a ver com decisões de engenharia do time do que com o Git em si.

Cada time pode escolher trabalhar de uma maneira diferente.

## Integração Contínua (*Continuous Integration*)

Segundo a prática de Integração Contínua, a mecânica fica um pouco diferente da tradicional criação de branches para o desenvolvimento de features ou grandes mudanças. Ela fica assim:

- Todos os desenvolvedores commitam continuamente na linha principal de desenvolvimento (no Git, "master branch"). Commitam correção de bugs, pequenas alterações e grandes alterações. **Evita-se ao máximo a criação de branches de desenvolvimento**.
- Em dado momento, um determinado snapshot da linha principal é escolhido para release. Vamos dizer que esta release foi nominada **versão 2.0**.
- Os desenvolvedores nunca pararam de commitar na linha principal e todos os commits posteriores àquele snapshot escolhido irão constituir no futuro a **versão 3.0**.
- Acontece que um bug foi encontrado e sua correção não pode esperar até a versão 3.0.
- Aqui é feito um branch de manutenção da **versão 2.0**. Ele é feito a partir daquele shapshot escolhido. A correção do bug é feita neste branch e reproduzida na linha principal. Se a **versão 2.0** já foi liberada, será liberada uma **versão 2.0.1** com a correção deste bug. Este branch servirá exclusivamente para manutenção da **versão estável 2.0**, ou seja, apenas para implementar correções de bug nesta versão. Grandes mudanças serão evitadas justamente para que a versão permaneça estável. As próximas liberações desta versão, com correção de bugs, serão **2.0.2**, **2.0.3** e assim sucessivamente. Todas as correções feitas aqui são replicadas na linha principal de modo que a **versão 3.0** não trará estes bugs de volta.
- Quando a **versão 3.0** for liberada (no mesmo modo que foi a versão 2.0 - a partir de um snapshot da linha principal), provavelmente a **versão 2.0** deixará de receber manutenção e aquele branch de manutenção tende a morrer. Para manutenção da versão 3.0 será criado um novo branch, que dará origem às versões 3.0.1, 3.0.2 e assim sucessivamente, tal qual ocorreu com a versão 2.0.

Uma forma de representar isso, seria:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

## Conclusão:

Os branches que serão criados depende das decisões de engenharia do time. Usando práticas de integração contínua, haverá geralmente **apenas dois branches ativos**:

- O *master branch*, que é a linha de desenvolvimento e também a linha de onde são geradas releases;
- E o branch de manutenção da última versão liberada.

Leia mais sobre outros aspectos e vantagens da Integração Contínua neste artigo do Martin Fowler: http://martinfowler.com/articles/continuousIntegration.html

Comment: Os branchs servem tbm para evitar conflito nos arquivos, caso dois usuários modificam o mesmo arquivo na mesma linha?

Comment: @DenerCarvalho Não. Se os dois usuários estiverem usando a mesma branch, um deles terá que resolver o conflito na hora que fizer commit/push; e se cada um estiver usando um branch distinto, este conflito terá que ser resolvido de qualquer modo na hora que for feito o merge entre os branches. Então, não, branch não serve para evitar conflito. É justamente o contrário que ocorre: quanto mais tempo o desenvolvimento ocorrer em branches distintos, mais conflitos haverá para resolver na hora do merge.

Answer (score 6):

Bom aqui na nossa empresa trabalhamos com um modelo próprio, mas que partiu da seguinte lógica: http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/ . Em termos gerais isso depende de você, se vai trabalhar com pull request por exemplo, é sugerido trabalhar com 2 branchs develop e a master, sendo que você fara um pull request para develop. E por aí vai.

Acredito que o link acima te ajude bastante, partimos desse pré suposto de 2 branch. Master e Developer.

Espero tê-lo ajudado.

Comment: Semelhante na empresa na qual trabalho, mas vejo que trabalhar com mais branches quando são vários clientes, versões diferentes e não sendo um SaaS, pode ocorrer algum bug em algum cliente que não comprou a última versão e você precisa corrigir. Depende o caso.

Answer (score 5):

Geralmente, você usa um segundo (terceiro, quarto e assim vai) *branch* para desenvolver algo sem interferir no desenvolvimento do *branch* principal, e assim que o desenvolvimento do segundo *branch* termina, um *merge* é realizado para combinar os dois códigos.

## Quantos *branches* são realmente úteis no Git?

Depende muito da quantidade de ramos de desenvolvimento estão ocorrendo em um dado período. Se você está desenvolvendo 5 características novas, a ideia é criar 5 *branches* que iniciam com uma cópia do código *`master`* e assim que estiverem prontos, executar *`merge`* para combinar os códigos e assim ter o código completo.

## Por que essa recomendação de começar a usar *branches* desde o início?

Isso depende mais do número de desenvolvedores/equipes deles envolvidas no projeto e designação de cada um. Em geral, cria-se um *branch* para desenvolver uma parte sem modificar em si o código estável anterior.

## Por que usar *branches* sempre?

Porque toda linha de desenvolvimento é um *branch*. [/piadaRUIM]

---

Porque cada *branch* representa um "assunto", um foco de desenvolvimento do projeto. Mesmo que você esteja só com uma linha de desenvolvimento, você tem um *branch*, que é geralmente chamado de *`master`* pelo GIT.

Answer (score 0):

> Acontece que nesses dois casos que identifiquei que branches seriam úteis, a utilidade vem do fato de existir um código estável que não é interessante mexer muito e querermos ter a liberdade de trabalhar em algo sem estragar esse código. Não consigo ver como que antes de termos um código estável branching possa ser útil.

Sempre teremos uma branch principal que é onde ficará o código estável. Ao iniciar o projeto, já temos uma branch inicial, que é a master. Realmente nesse início ainda não haverá código estável, porque nada foi implementado. Ainda assim, podemos criar uma branch a partir da master, implementar uma nova feature e após ela ser devidamente testada, fazer um merge para a master. Que nesse caso será a branch principal.

Nesse ponto, não tem problema se alguma outra feature que está sendo implementada, ainda não está funcionando corretamente. Porque só adicionamos na branch principal o que está funcionando. Conforme as outras features forem sendo finalizadas, elas serão adicionadas na branch principal.

Desse forma, sempre teremos um código estável em uma determinada branch desde o início.