# Qual é a diferença entre um "branch" e uma "tag"?

Tags: git, terminologia, versionamento

No Git, qual é a diferença entre um *branch* e uma *tag*?

Comment: Só deixar um adendo, que conversarmos a um bom tempo, muitos repositórios, como o do Laravel por exemplo, usam os branchs pra dividir as versões pois eles costumam continuar a fazer updates em ambos branchs.

Comment: http://imasters.com.br/artigo/21127/software-livre/como-trabalhar-com-tags-no-git?trace=1519021197&source=single aqui explica bem a diferencia entre ambas.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

A [*tag*](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Tagging) é apenas uma marca, em geral, em um [*branch*](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v1/Git-Branching-What-a-Branch-Is) específico que marca uma situação em um determinado momento.

O *branch* tradicional deve ser algo experimental, algo em paralelo, algo que potencialmente será incorporado ao desenvolvimento principal, ao *branch* principal.

A *tag* costuma marcar um *release*, uma versão ou algo assim. Então a *tag* é apenas um apontador para um *commit* específico enquanto que um *branch* é um caminho, um galho de desenvolvimento.

A *tag* é apenas um nome que se dá para um estado do desenvolvimento. Desta forma fica fácil acessar aquele estado sempre que for preciso.

No Git não há custo em ter uma *tag*, é algo simbólico e não ocupa espaço no repositório. Você não altera o que está na *tag*. É um ramo estático que pode ser usado a qualquer momento. A *tag* será usada eventualmente, quando há algum evento importante no desenvolvimento e que ali precise desta marca para voltar nela outras vezes. Normalmente este evento é um *release*.

Se trabalha no desenvolvimento sempre em cima de *branches* através dos *commits*. É nele que se faz o *merge* do estado anterior com o que foi desenvolvido agora. O *branch* vai recebendo evoluções do desenvolvimento. É incentivado que se faça um novo *branch*, sempre que possível, quando vai iniciar uma nova linha de desenvolvimento.

[image: Branch/tag no Git]

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Taí uma coisa que temos que aprender a fazer aqui onde eu trabalho  (o último parágrafo)

Comment: No `SVN` isso é diferente né? @bigown

Comment: No SVN Temos o Trunk que funciona como a linha principal da árvore!

Comment: @WallaceMaxters Nem todos incentivam o uso de branches - muitos as evitam. Trabalhei em projetos com todos commitando na mesma branch, e trabalhei em outros onde o custo de integração entre branchs foi sendo reduzido com integrações a intervalos cada vez menores, até que as integrações foram completamente removidas (todos commitando na mesma linha), trazendo muitos ganhos. Talvez os problemas na sua empresa sejam melhor resolvidos de outra forma. Dê uma lida sobre a prática de **Integração Contínua** (*Contínuos Integration*) aqui: http://martinfowler.com/articles/continuousIntegration.html

Comment: @WallaceMaxters E nesta resposta há um resumo muito singelo sobre utilizar uma única linha de desenvolvimento e utilizar branches apenas para construir releases de manutenção em versões estáveis: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/48866/14584

Answer (score 22):

Para ficar clara a diferença, pense no repositório do Git como um grafo, sendo que cada nó deste grafo é um *commit*.

**Tag** é um ponteiro que você usa para apontar para qualquer nó deste grafo.

A tag, normalmente, é usado para marcar versões do sistema. Exemplo: você pode criar uma tag `v1.2.1` em determinado ponto do seu repositório, continuar commitando no repositório e voltar para esta tag `v1.2.1` facilmente.

**Branch** também é um ponteiro para um nó mas, diferente da tag, a branch pode gerar uma ramificação dentro deste grafo.

[Veja o grafo](http://qualidadegarantida.blogspot.com.br/2015/03/o-que-e-uma-branch-no-git.html) a seguir. O `master` é uma branch, assim como `minha-branch` é. Há também uma tag `v1.2.1` criada, apontando para o nó `N03`:

```
                            |minha-branch|
                                  |
                                  |
                             .---N05
                            /
N01<---N02<---N03<---N04<--´-----N06
               |                  |
               |                  |
           |v1.2.1|           |master|
```

Criar uma tag ou uma branch é tão simples e rápido quanto [escrever 41 bytes](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Branches-in-a-Nutshell) em um arquivo no disco.

Como pode perceber, dentro do Git, elas são iguais, mas tratadas de maneiras diferentes:

- Tão iguais que você não consegue ter uma branch com o mesmo nome de uma tag.
- Tão diferentes que você não consegue commitar em uma tag (a não ser que crie uma branch a partir desta tag!), mas pode commitar em uma branch.

Comment: +1 pelo desenho, rsrs

Comment: Acho que o comentário sobre o SVN não se aplica...pelo que sei, no SVN branchs e tags são idênticos,e o custo de criação é muito baixo também.

Comment: @zentrunix, removido. Na época que eu usava uma branch no SVN este processo era muito pesado, mas não sei como está hoje em dia o SVN, acredito que tenha evoluído e melhorado.

Answer (score 12):

**Branch:**

Uma ramificação da sua "árvore" principal de desenvolvimento, geralmente criado para gerar correções ou novas implementações, quando esse branch chega no final podemos fazer um `Merge` para a ramificação principal do seu projeto.

**Tag:**

Podemos olhar a tag com um "repositório" de releases das versões estáveis, essas versões não devem ser alteradas.

```
Tag
--release 1.0
---release 1.0.1
----release 2.0
-----release 2.1
```

**Finalizando**

O `Branch` fica com a responsabilidade de receber as modificações(commits) durante o sprint do desenvolvimento a cada nova implementação é recomendável gerar novas branches conforme o desenvolvimento vai evoluindo. 
Quando o projeto já está maduro e estável é gerada uma nova release que será armazenada na `TAG` do repositório

Answer (score 4):

Só um complemento a tudo que ja foi falado, existem 2 tipos de tag:

#### Light-weight tags

Que como já foi dito são como links simbólicos, apenas apontam para um commit.

Quanto a espaço no repositório, o git cria somente um arquivo com o nome da tag dentro, portanto é mínimo.

#### Annotated tags

Resumindo são tags com um pouco mais de informação, além de apontarem para o commit, também armazena o nome e email do criador da tag, data, e mensagem da tag, tipo a mensagem do commit.

Já que contem muito mais informação do que uma light-weight ela acaba sendo armazenada como um objeto completo do git, logo ocupa mais espaço do que a light-weight

Answer (score 2):

**Branch** são ramificações (ao pé da letra) de um trabalho em paralelo do que já está em produção ou na master. Usamos branchs para codificar alguma funcionalidade específica ou então para corrigir bugs, por exemplo.

Já uma **tag** utilizamos para definir uma nova versão do produto. Por exemplo um sistema que estava em desenvolvimento e foi concluída a versão 1.0. Daí então se cria uma **tag** dizendo que a partir dali foi lançada a tal versão.