# Como disponibilizar um pacote criado com composer?

Tags: laravel, versionamento, composer

O json abaixo faz parte do arquivo composer.json de um pacote que criei:

```
{
    "name": "libspkgs/utils",
    "type": "library",
    "description": "Descrição aqui.",
    "keywords": ["key1", "key2"],
    "homepage": "https://endereco.com",
    "license": "MIT",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "Nome do autor",
            "email": "email@gmail.com"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.6.27"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Pkg\\": "lib/"
            }
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev"
}
```

Estou adicionando o mesmo ao `Laravel` desta forma:

```
composer require libspkgs/utils v1.0.0
```

Mas como faço para adicionar sempre a ultima `release`?

Comment: Aonde está hospedado seu pacote? fui buscar no [packagist](https://packagist.org/) e não encontrei ...

Comment: Virgilio consegui fazer a publicação em: packagist.org/packages/crphp/wmi

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento é duplicada, kkkkk

Comment: @WallaceMaxters do meu ponto de vista sim, mas já votei pra fechar e cancelaram (consideraram que não era dup).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Disponibilização padrão de um package

Primeiramente, você precisa ter uma conta no [Packagist](https://packagist.org/). Atualmente (ano de 2016), você pode usar a sua conta do [Github](https://github.com/) para criá-la.

Depois, você precisa ter um repositório público para ser apontado pelo Packagist.

É importante falar que, por conta de questões de organização, o nome do repositório tenha o mesmo *library name* que vai ser usado no Composer.

Por exemplo: para um pacote chamado `vendor_name/library_name` no Packagist, seria importante que o seu repositório no Github chamasse `library_name`.

> **Observação**: *Vendor Name* é o nome do "fornecedor" da biblioteca e *Library Name* é o nome da biblioteca. O Composer utiliza "vendor name/library name" como padrão de nome para as bibliotecas.

<sub>**Nota**: para continuar esse "tutorial", você deve ter em mente que você precisa ter um considerável conhecimento sobre ferramentas de versionamento (como o GIT, por exemplo).</sub>

Depois de criar seu repositório, recomendo seguir alguns padrões para a criação da sua biblioteca.

Por exemplo,  um padrão muito utilizado, é definir o seu namespace a partir da pasta `src` do seu projeto:

```
library_name/
    .gitignore
    composer.json
    src/
       Hello.php
```

Assim, poderíamos configurar o composer.json da seguinte forma:

```
 "name" : "vendor_name/library_name",

 "required" : {
      "php" : ">=5.4"
 },

 "autoload" : {
       "psr-4" : {
           "VendorName\\LibraryName\\" :  "src/"
       }
 }
```

Sua classe `Hello.php` dentro de `src`, obviamente, deve ficar assim:

```
namespace VendorName\LibraryName;

class Hello {}
```

**Nota**: Para testar sua biblioteca antes de enviá-la, é necessário rodar o comando `composer dump` para gerar o autoload. Caso possua dependências a outras libraries, você deve usar `composer install`.

Depois de tudo isso, você pode fazer o commit e o push de suas alterações para o repositório:

```
>>> cd library_name
>>> git commit -am "my first commit"
>>> git push
```

Após isso, você precisa submeter a sua biblioteca para o Packagist, através desse formulário:

[image]

Depois da submissão, é necessário inserir o seu TOKEN API do Packagist nas configurações do seu repositório do Github.

Você deve clicar na opção "settings" e em seguida "integrations and services". Depois disso, na opção "add service" você deve escolher "packagist".

[image]

Depois disso, você deve clicar no serviço "packagist" que foi adicionado, e configurá-lo, colocando seu usuário e o token do Packagist.

Veja:

[image]

O Token que deverá ser adicionado, pode ser encontrado nessa tela do Packagist:

[image]

Depois de fazer tudo isso, você já poderá testar se sua biblioteca está funcionando corretamente utilizando o comando:

```
composer require vendor_name/library_name
```

## Mas e o versionamento?

Você precisa definir uma tag no seu repositório para poder demarcar uma versão "utilizável" da sua biblioteca. Por exemplo, se você já tem certeza que sua biblioteca está pronta para o uso, poderá definir uma versão para ela.

Você pode definir uma tag dessa forma:

```
git tag 0.0.1
```

Depois, para enviá-la ao seu repositório, você precisa rodar o comando:

```
git push --tags
```

Note que as tags precisam seguir um padrão. Eu geralmente, sempre uso os três conjuntos de números.

As versões no seu Packagist será organizado de acordo com esses números.

Por exemplo;

```
1.0.0
0.0.3
0.0.2
0.0.1
```

Para a resposta não ficar muito longa, sugiro a leitura de alguns posts do site:

- [Qual é a diferença entre um "branch" e uma "tag"?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/80583/qual-%C3%A9-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-um-branch-e-uma-tag)
- [Quando incrementar a versão usando Semantic Versioning?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/51817/quando-incrementar-a-vers%C3%A3o-usando-semantic-versioning)

Comment: Obrigado Wallace, consegui. Veja: https://packagist.org/packages/crphp/wmi