# Como criar um projeto no GitLab utilizando o git?

Tags: git, gitlab

Podemos facilmente criar um projeto no *GitLab* e "sincronizá-lo" pelo *git*:

```
$ git clone git@gitlab.com:user/teste.git
```

---

**Mas e para fazer o contrário?**

Criar a pasta e o projeto local, e enviar como um "novo" no *GitLab*?

Comment: No Github, eu faço o repositório local e o remoto, e depois mando um primeiro commit

Comment: @mutlei Mas o commit é só local. Ele não envia para o GitLab...

Comment: Sim. Depois você dá o push pra enviar o commit pro remoto.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Eu acho que você está falando de enviar definir um repositório remoto para um projeto existente.

## Repositório Local do Zero

Eu costumo fazer assim:

- Crio a pasta do projeto
- Inicializo o repositório local dentro da pasta que acabei de criar.O comando é `git init`
- Depois disso, adicione os arquivos que serão enviados no primeiro commit. Rode `git add .` para selecionar todos os arquivos (opcional, se quiser fazer um por um você pode, é apenas um exemplo)
- Faça o commit. `git commit -m "primeiro commit"`
- Adicione o local de origem. `git remote add origin git@gitlab.com:user/teste.git`
- Faça o push inicial para o seu servidor: `git push -u origin master`

Prontinho, você está enviando os dados do local a partir de um repositório já existente na sua máquina.

Resumo do que fiz acima, através do BASH:

```
>>> mkdir projeto
>>> cd projeto
>>> git init 
>>> git add .
>>> git commit -m "primeiro commit"
>>> git remote add origin git@gitlab.com:user/teste.git
>>> git push -u origin master
```

## Repositório local com origem existente

Caso você esteja tentando usar um repositório já existente que tenha outra origem, você não vai conseguir usar o comando `git remote add origin`.  Nesse caso, use `git remote set-url origin git@gitlab.com:user/teste.git`, **mas apenas se você já tiver um repositório com origin**, e não se tiver criando um do zero.

Depois basta fazer o `git push -u origin master`.

## Explicando os comandos

**`git-init`**

Inicia um repositório `git`. Ao rodar esse comando, você está dizendo que, a partir de agora, aquela diretório terá o controle de versão do GIT.

**`git-add`**

Adiciona o conteúdo de um ou mais arquivos para o índice de mudança. Quando você faz `git add readme.txt`, está dizendo que as mudanças feitas em `readme.txt` irão ser salvas no próximo commit.

Eu gosto de usar `git add` e ir adicionando as mudanças que fiz de acordo com um tópico.

Por exemplo:

Eu criei um botão na página de cadastro de usuários que verifica se o e-mail é válido. Para isso, criei o botão em `criar-usuario.html` e em `criar-usuario.js` fiz a chamada ajax que vai fazer essa consulta.

Você pode fazer assim pra processar as modificações:

```
 >>> git add views/criar-usuario.html js/criar-usuario.js
```

Em seguida, quando você fizer o `commit`, apenas os dois arquivo serão adicionados à lista de modificações.

Quando se usa o ponto (`git add .`), você está dizendo que todos os arquivos serão adicionados.

**`git commit -m`**

Processa as mudanças informadas em `git add` e adiciona ao histórico de mudança. No caso acima, a flag `-m` indica que você está informando a mensagem de commit diretamente na chamada do comando. Se você usar apenas `git commit`, uma janela que geralmente usa o `vim` ou o `nano` (editor de código comuns no Linux) se abrirá pra você colocar a mensagem do `commit`.

As mensagens do commit precisam descrever o que você fez.

Usando o exemplo anterior:

```
>>> git add js/cadastro-usuario.js views/cadastro-usuario.html
>>> git commit -m "Adicionando botão de consulta de e-mail"
```

**`git remote add origin url_do_repostiório`**

Você está dizendo que o lugar onde ficará salvo as mudanças do GIT remotamente será a url informada.

Esse comando é usado geralmente quando você cria um repositório com `git init`, pois o mesmo apenas adiciona o controle de versão. O `git remote add origin` informa o servidor onde você salvará as mudanças.

**`git push -u origin master`**

O `git push` envia as informações dos commits que você criou para o servidor.
Os commits vão sendo adicionados à fila e é possível ver quais não foram enviados através do comando `git status`.

O `-u` geralmente é usado no primeiro commit e o `origin master` indica que o `branch` de origem será o `master`. O `master` geralmente é o `branch` padrão do GIT.

Não vou me alongar demais sobre Branchs. Dê uma lida sobre isso aqui:

- [Qual é a diferença entre um branch e uma tag?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/80583/qual-%C3%A9-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-um-branch-e-uma-tag)

Comment: Faltava o remote add! Cara, o que é esse `origin`? Seria a pasta que estou?

Comment: @rbz `origin` é o repositório remoto.

Comment: @rbz dá uma olhadinha no resumo (os comandos)