# Quando devo manter ou deletar um branch?

Tags: git, versionamento

Estou trabalhando em um projeto e estou começando a utilizar um sistema de controle de versionamento, o Git. Quando crio um `branch` para introduzir uma nova funcionalidade e após a finalização da mesma, realizo um `merge` com o `master`.

Qual é a melhor prática a se adotar com relação aos `branchs` criados, deletar ou mantê-los? Em que tipos de situações devo optar por deletar e não deletar?

Comment: Relacionado: [Quando branches são uteis no Git?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/48855/14584)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Cada pessoa tem um fluxo próprio. Em tese depois de fazer o *merge* você pode deletá-lo.

Você pode querer mantê-lo por algum tempo para facilitar a manutenção se encontrar algum problema especificamente em algo feito naquele *branch*, mas não adianta manter por muito tempo, depois que o código começa ser alterado vai ficando mais fácil mexer à partir do *master*.

Pode manter por motivos históricos, mas raramente é útil de fato.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Obrigado @bigown! Aproveitando a situação, em um projeto, o correto é sempre tralharmos em branchs ao invés de trabalharmos diretamente no master?

Comment: Sim, o ideal é isto mesmo. Trabalhar no *master* é gambi da grossa.

Comment: Entendi, muito obrigado @bigown!

Comment: Em relação ao versionamento, existem também os contextos de gerência de conhecimento e gerência de produção do projeto. Seguindo isso, o correto seria ter uma política própria para cada projeto.

Comment: @Duds Idéias modernas de desenvolvimento de software (para muitos já um pouco antigas até) defendem o commit contínuo diretamente na linha *master* (também chamada *main* ou *trunk* em outras ferramentas). Há vários anos eu uso este modelo com sucesso em muitos projetos, e já vi funcionar em muitos outros. Pesquise por ***continuous integration*** e ***continuous delivery*** e dê uma olhada nessa resposta: [Quando branches são uteis no Git?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/48866/14584)

Answer (score 3):

No Git, branches são apenas ponteiros (referências) a commits em um grafo acíclico dirigido (DAG) de commits. Isto significa que deletar um branch remove apenas referências a commits, o que pode tornar alguns commits no DAG inalcançáveis, portanto, invisíveis. Mas todos os commits que estavam em um branch deletado ainda estarão no repositório, ao menos até que os commits inalcançáveis sejam podados ("pruned", por exemplo usando git gc).

Repare que `git branch -d` recusará a deleção de um branch se não puder garantir que ao removê-lo, não deixará commits inalcançáveis. Se realmente quiser removê-lo, precisa usar `git branch -D` para forçar a deleção de um branch que pode deixar commits inalcançáveis.

Repare também que commits inalcançáveis, se existirem, são apenas aqueles entre a última ponta de um branch deletado e um commit que tenha sido mesclado em outro branch existente, ou o ponto onde o branch surgiu; o que estiver por último. Por exemplo nesta situação:

```
----O----*----*----/M----*    <-- master <-- HEAD
     \            /
      \--.----.--/--x---y     <-- branch deletado
```

Apenas os commits 'x' e 'y' ficarão indisponíveis após deletar o branch.

Este texto foi extraído e traduzido da resposta do [Jakub Narębski](https://stackoverflow.com/users/46058/jakub-nar%C4%99bski) em [outra pergunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2613903/does-deleting-a-branch-in-git-remove-it-from-the-history), onde você pode ler mais sobre isso em inglês.